# Position body background image relative to child div

Tags: css, background-image, bootstrap-5

I need to position the background image of `<body>` relative to one of the child `<div>`s.

```
<body> 
    <div>content</div>       <-- place background image of body relative to this div
    <div>other content</div>
</body>
```

[image: Placing body's background image relative to child element with content]

The background image's size is bigger that the viewport and its top left corner shall be placed outside of the viewport.

**My unsuccessful approach**

My approach was to add the image as `<img>` with negative `z-index` and `position: absolute` but this approach adds horizontal scrollbars due to the image size

```
<body>
    <div style="position: relative">
        <img 
            src="..." 
            style="position: absolute; top: -100px; left: -400px; width: 800px; height: 600px; z-index: -1;" 
        />
        <div>content</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: How is the size of the image to be decided? Is it relative to its 'natural' size but proportional to something like the width of the body, or the width of the content div or....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your approach by using overflow-x:hidden; on the overflowed element or
try position absolute with display inline

Comment: ``overflow-x: hidden`` on the ``<body>`` was the solution. ``display: inline`` was not required

Answer (score 0):

If the image is going to be a background of `<body>` using CSS rather than trying to insert it onto the HTML page as an `<img>` then you could perhaps use `50% 50%` to position it?

`50% 50%` will put the image exactly in the center though.

```
body{
  background: ( path-to-your-image ) 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

So you might want to try something like this to shift it over to the left a bit.

```
body{
  background: ( path-to-your-image ) 15% 50% no-repeat;
}
```